# How to recover password from ubuntu installed on sd card?

Tags: sd-card, password-recovery, arm, beagleboard

I've got my Ubuntu 13.04 ARM installed on the SD Card. System was working on beaglebone black. The image was installed following instructions in this wiki page: http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Method_1:_Download_a_Complete_Pre-Configured_Image . Well, system did boot automatically after inserting, everything worked pretty well.

Now the main issue - I have changed the default password ("temppwd") and forgot the new one (After changing password I didn't use the system for quite a while). #sic!

Now I'm wondering what can I do to get my system back for good. The conventional ways of recovering password described so widely here and on the other forums don't work in this case, because:

1) The system is on the SD Card

2) I don't have GRUB installed on the BeagleBone Black.

So now I have got two systems. One is running on the internal eMMC card of the BBB, which is working correctly and I know the password to it, so I can normally boot the system (Ubuntu 13.04). The other one is on the SD Card and I lost the password to it (Ubuntu 13.04 aswell). When I try to put the SD Card into the BBB after booting the onboard system (so, that it wouldn't try to boot from SD Card), I cannot mount the SD Card then:

```
mount: can't find /dev/mmcblk0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

What can I do to recover my system?

Regards
rogi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition is (normally) not password protected, so you are having two separate problems:

1. How to mount my SD card
2. How to reset a password in a root partition by use of a different boot system

For question number 1, if it is complaining about fstab it means you did not use the complete command, it is missing data which it looks for in fstab.

The directory to mount to should already exist, so first make it by using:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdcard
```

Now the command should be:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/sdcard
```

( and sometimes additional settings like type and mount options but normally this is not necessary )
if it is not working it could be because the partition is actually named differently, you can check by inserting the sdcard and after a couple of seconds run `dmesg`, the last lines will mention the disk.

Now for problem number 2,chroot to your installation:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/sdcard/
```

Change the root password:

`passwd`

Exit from the chroot:

`exit`

Comment: This will not work if the host arch is not ARM, which is rarely the case as most ARM systems don't have two SD card slots.